# CakePHP: Validate date as 'dmy' but save to MySQL as correct date

Tags: php, mysql, validation, date, cakephp

I have a CakePHP 2.7 app. In my model I have the following validation:

```
public $validate = [
    'trip_start' => [
        'rule' => ['date', 'dmy'],
        'message' => 'Date format is DD/MM/AAAA'
    ];
```

This work fine for client side validation and I can validate the user is selecting the date correctly.

But for saving to MySQL, the format expected is YYYY-mm-dd. What's the "standard" solution for this? Modify the beforeSave? The problem is that there needs to be 2 different validations. One in the format I expect the user to enter a date (even with a datepicker) and another in the format MySQL expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CakeTime class is made for it.

```
App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
echo CakeTime::format('2015-07-24', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

return 24-07-2015

in your case you just have to reformat your data after the validation:

```
public function afterValidate(){
$this->request->data['Model']['fieldName'] = CakeTime::format($this->request->data['Model']['fieldName'], '%Y-%m-%d');
}
```

Comment: You should mention that this is a callback function of CakePHP so you don't need to call it manually. It will just happen after the validation and I guess before save.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html